# Python scipy.optimize.curve_fit Failing to Fit Function

Tags: python, scipy, physics, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a LRC Circuit Transfer Function but curve_fit doesn't seem to be able to make a fit. I have tried different initial values as well as trying to implement scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.

Below is my fit attempt which produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohlVW.png) after plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

def f(freq, R, L, C):
    w = 2*np.pi*np.array(freq) # Convert frequency to angular frequency
    return R*w*C/np.sqrt((1-C*L*w**2)**2+(C*w*R)**2) # Series Transfer Function

name = ['R', 'L', 'C']
p0 = [1000,0.07,0.0000001] # Actual values of circuit components.

params, covariance = curve_fit(f, np.array(x), np.array(y), p0)
print(params)
```

I'm not quite sure if the issue lies with my initial parameters, or if the  Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is doing something completely different.

When I tried limiting my fit to the strictly increasing portion of the function, the fit seemed to work perfectly, leading me to think my error must be related to the shape of the function.

Does anyone have a hint as to why I would be getting such strange fits?

Comment: Note: your `f` is a LCR series measuring the voltage over R. If `w**2 = 1  / ( L * C)` the `f` returns `1`, i.e. at resonance the voltage drops over R only. As your maximum is at `0.4` I'd say you got the wrong model.

Comment: I see that you import differential_evolution for estimating initial parameter values for curve_fit, but have not yet used it in your code. I think I can get you going, but will need your data. Would you please link to the data, or if it is not large, add it to your question?

Comment: Your image suggests that you have an RLC parallel circuit. Are you having this in series with an R0? The you might want to fit `w * r * l / np.sqrt( ( r * r0 * (1 - w**2 * l * c ) )**2 + ( w * l * ( r + r0 ) )**2 )`

Comment: You can guess R0/R from the maximum value and L*C from its position. From the slope at small frequencies you get L/R0 etc.

Comment: it looks like your model function is too sharp to match your data.  It does seem like the model requires the maximum value to be 1, not ~0.4.  It may be that the response function needs to be broadened or damped by some other term.

Comment: @MNewville The sharpness is not the problem. The problem is that the maximum of the given function is always `1`. To compensate for this systematic mismatch the fit naturally narrows the graph. The model in this form is simply wrong and cannot match the data.

Comment: BTW if the is an RLC parallel in series with an R0 you need to know at least one value, otherwise the problem is scalable.

Comment: @mikuszefski Thank you for your response. Quite right! It seems I failed to notice that my data capturing device was recording Vresistor and not Vresistor/Vsource. This would explain the bad model.
I believe the data is for a series RLC circuit since if it were parallel the transfer function would be passing through a minimum and not a maximum as is the case for series, unless I'm mistaken? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @JamesPhillipsIt seems my function, as pointed out by mikuszefski, was not correct. I'll update this thread as soon as I correct my data issue and get my fit working - or fail to do so. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: @MNewville Thanks for the response. As I've told the others, it seems I do have a data issue. Quite right about the maximum value problem - I should've noticed. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, whether it is a minimum or max depends on how you order and where you measure. You have series( R0, parallel( r, l, c ) ) and you measure over the parallel rlc you'll see a max at resonance. As I said, if you have series( l, c, r ) and measure over r this will be U0 at resonance. If, however, this is actually U and you put 0.4 Volts as U0, you got it. You can fix it or fit it, thereby considering, e.g. some resistance in the inductance.

Comment: BTW I came up with parallel as you image states so.

Comment: ...and again this is scalable, i.e. there are infinite combinations rlc. You need to know one.

Comment: ....and can you change the title please, it is definitively not a Gaussian...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution that makes a parameter guess using the physics behind:

One knows that the maximum is at 'U'. Moreover, it is known that `1/(L*C)= (2 * pi * fMax )**2`. Eventually we can use that `U(f)` is approximately `2 * pi * f* R * C` for small `f`. From this equations one can calculate guesses easily

However, `L` and `C`  can be fitted only relative to `R`. Therefore `R` is set to unity. To show this scaling behaviour I made a second plot where `R` is set to 1000 Ohm. If `R` -> `a * R` then `L` -> `a * L`, and `C` -> `C / a`. The according graphs are identical as they should.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def rlc_series( f, u , l, c, R=1):
    r = R
    w = 2 * np.pi * f
    return u * w * r * c / np.sqrt( ( 1 - w**2 * l * c )**2 + ( w * r * c )**2 )

fuData = np.loadtxt( "ohlVW.txt", delimiter=',' )
fuData = fuData[ fuData[:,0].argsort()]

### r=1
guessU = max( fuData[::,1] )
guessC = 1. / ( 2 * np.pi ) * ( fuData[ 1, 1 ] - fuData[ 0, 1 ] ) / (fuData[ 1, 0 ] - fuData[ 0, 0 ] ) / guessU
guessL = 1. / ( 2 * np.pi * fuData[ fuData[:,1].argmax() ,0 ] )**2 * 1./guessC
guess = [ guessU, guessL, guessC ]

sol, pcov = curve_fit(rlc_series, fuData[::,0], fuData[::,1], p0=guess )
print sol

fList = np.linspace( 0, 4000, 1000 )
uGList = np.fromiter( ( rlc_series( x, *guess ) for x in fList ), np.float )
uFList = np.fromiter( ( rlc_series( x, *sol ) for x in fList ), np.float )
uOtherList = np.fromiter( ( rlc_series( x, sol[0], sol[1]*1000, sol[2] / 1000., R=1000 ) for x in fList ), np.float )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( fuData[::,0], fuData[::,1] , marker ='o', ls='', label='Data' )
ax.plot( fList, uGList, label='Guess')
ax.plot( fList, uFList, label='Fit ($R=1\;\Omega$)')
ax.plot( fList, uOtherList, ls='--', label='scaled for $R=1000\;\Omega$')
ax.set_xlabel('$f\;\mathrm{(Hz)}$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('$U\;\mathrm{(V)}$', fontsize=16)
ax.legend( loc=0 )
plt.show()
```

providing:

```
>> [3.85138538e-01 2.95465209e-04 3.49390461e-05]
```

[image: fit]

Comment: BTW, data is subset of OP's data.

Comment: This is a very intriguing solution. Thank you.